# apt-get (Debian 9) openssh-server package keeps prompting for config file options - ignoring options?

Tags: apt

I am trying to do non-interactive upgrades.  It seems to works until I get to the openssh-server package.  openssh-server pops up an interactive prompt which doesn't even work. It is "frozen" and I have to cntrl-C out of it, manually kill the process and then repair it to continue.  What am I doing wrong?

Note, I can see it using the options I think should work... but it keeps prompting me anyway?

```
 /usr/bin/dpkg --force-confdef --force-confold --status-fd 17 --configure --pending


ssh -T $i 'export TERM=linux; sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade';
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem was I needed to add "-q" to all of that?  This is working for me now:

```
sudo TERM=linux DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade && /sbin/reboot'
```